# if else statement in map function reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

You don't have to read the whole code, just read the comment in the `editQuantity` function and in `showOrderItem` function, **specially in the showOrderItem function** and my problem is i think just silly, as both of my function are working as they supposed to work,

*editQuantity function supposed to change the state, it changing it, i checked by adding the console line.

*showOrderItem function supposed display the item, he is doing that job as well.

My problem is, i try to add `conditional rendering` in the showOrderItem function that not working, even though i am able to change the state.

Please read the comment in showOrderItem function, to see where is the problem:

```
import React from 'react';


export default class ShowOrder extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            quantityEditing:this.props.orderItems,

        }
    }

    editQuantity(item){
        const order=this.state.quantityEditing;
        for(var i =0; i<order.length; i++){

            if(order[i].item==item){
                console.log(order[i].orderQuantityEditing)
                order[i].orderQuantityEditing=true;
                this.setState({order:this.state.quantityEditing})
                console.log(order[i].orderQuantityEditing)

            }
        }
    }
    showOrderItem(){

        const style = {cursor:'pointer'}
        const orderItems=this.state.quantityEditing;
        console.log(orderItems)
        const orderItem=orderItems.map((item,index)=>


        <p>
        {orderItems.orderQuantityEditing ? 'some':
        <span style={style} onClick={this.editQuantity.bind(this,item.item)}>
//as you can see in here i added conditional rendering, that if orderItems.orderQuantityEditing is true display me some, but that's not working --orderItems.orderQuantityEditing ? 'some'(this part) does not matter how many times i click on property it never display me my string 'some'
            {item.quantity}</span>}
        <span style={style}> {item.item}</span>
        <span style={style}> Q</span>
        <span style={style}> N</span>
        <span style={style}> X</span>
        </p>

        );

        return orderItem;
    }
    render(){

        return(
        <div>
        {this.showOrderItem()}

        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
{orderItems.orderQuantityEditing ? 
    'some'
     :
     <span style={style} onClick{this.editQuantity.bind(this,item.item)}>
```

I think you need to write this:

```
{item.orderQuantityEditing ? 
     'some'
      :
      <span style={style} onClick={this.editQuantity.bind(this,item.item)}>
```

Because you are using `map`, and item will be each `object` of `array`, so you need to use item to access that property. During the `for loop`, when changing the `state` you wrote:

```
order[i].orderQuantityEditing=true;
```

That it proper, order will be an `array` and you need to provide the index to access particular `object` of that.

Comment: oh man so  i was right i did some thing silly, i am losing my mind over this, thanks for the help, just let me check one more time

Comment: one more thing, i think instead of `this.setState({order:this.state.order})` it should be `this.setState({ orderQuantityEditing : order})` ??

Comment: yup you are right, that line is wrong, how the hell my code was working before,